How to measure objects in Blender 4.2
I am looking for the option allowing a user to measure selected objects in Edit or Object mode.
It used to be in Viewport Overlays, but isn't there anymore:

I would like to display the size of the objects that are selected on the screen, edge length but also object width or height, etc.
I couldn't find an answer anywhere and it seems that questions related to measuring that are only a year old are outdated - as my menu doesn't look like that at all.
This official documentation page makes very little sense to me because the screenshot is cropped and there is no "Measure" in the Toolbar.

What Blender version are you using? In comments on answers below, you're saying that things don't look like what's displayed, but that might be because we're looking in different versions?

I use this one

I will try and compile the other answers to this question in this answer, in a clear and concise way. I tested everything in Blender 4.2.1 LTS version.
Mesh Edit Mode Overlays
If you select a mesh object (not a curve), and go into edit mode, you will find a menu called Mesh Edit Mode Overlays, which, as the name suggests, gives you access to some handy overlays when in Mesh Edit Mode.
As @gladys points out in their answer, you find said menu next to the Viewport Overlays button.
These overlays only show on selected edges or faces.

Measure Tool
The Measure tool, that lives in the Toolbar, lets you drag from one place to another to get the distance between those two points. If Snapping enabled, the Measure tool lets you snap to vertices, edges, edge centres, and faces.
But as @moonboots points out in their answer, you can use Ctrl while using the tool to snap it to above listed things too.

MeasureIt Add-on
The MeasureIt Add-on is an add-on that was bundled in Blender with Blender version 4.1. Nowadays you can get it via the Extensions, as it is a community made add-on. Make sure you enable  the add-on after installing it, if it isn't already.
This add-on adds a collapsable tab in the View tab of the viewport (if the panel is closed, press N while hovering over the viewport with your mouse).
The Show/Hide button will show or hide all the created measurements.
You can add a new Segment measurement to all selected edges by pressing Segment. They will appear in the viewport as well as in the list under the tab Items. If the lines displayed are way too long or short, or text should be bigger/smaller, you can edit that, on a per measurement basis in the Items tab, using the cogwheel button next to the respective item. There you can change text size, separation length etc.

To make all future measurements have certain settings, you can open the Configuration tab, just beneath the Items tab, and change the values to your liking.

Thanks to
Thanks to both @gladys and @moonboots contributions before mine, and their insightful images which I reused in this answer.

In Edit mode you can click on the mesh edit button next to the overlay button.


Unfortunately my version differs from yours

@MicroMachine, this definitely works in blender 4.2.0 and 4.2.2

@MicroMachine you have a curve selected, instead of a mesh. Make sure you have a mesh as your active selection when going into edit mode.

@lajawi is the measuring process different when measuring  mesh and a curve?

@MicroMachine You can't use the edge length on curves, because there are no actual edges, just representations of the mathematical curve.

To add to Gladys' answer, there's also the MeasureIt Tool (it's an addon), select the edge and click on Show, Segment and on the gear button if you want to change the font size:

Also you have the Measure tool, click on Ctrl to snap on the vertices:


Where does one find this Measure It addon? It's not included with Blender? Mine doesn't have it I'm upset that they keep changing everything around every other week, but absolute basics are nowhere to be found

In 4.2, click on the Get Extensions button in Preferences and type MeasureIt then Install

I don't see a gear but I think I'm getting closer? what an absolute obstacle course this is

It's under Items, you need to scroll down

I think I'm following your instructions but nothing looks readable it's just a big mess

you need to decrease the Distance (under Text Size)

@MicroMachine the image you attached shows your object is really small (only 1cm wide). The MeasureIt add-on has some settings to make the lines not as long, you can find them on a segment basis, in the gear icon as shown in this answer, or under the configuration tab, then Separation (this will only affect segments created after you've set this value). I've set this value to 0.001, opposed to 0.100, which would get you a desired result.

@lajawi I'm struggling to understand, do I have to set the Measure It settings to 0.001 before I create my object in the scene? I selected all the edges and clicked on the gear and changed the value but the blue lines stay as long as they were

All these tools allow you to measure the segments, they don't allow you to change their length to the desired value, I don't know if such a tool exists

@MicroMachine Only the measurement you're editing will get the new length. You'll have to do it for each and every one of them.
