Can I customize viewport overlay font?

Can I customize viewport overlay font?
It is hard to see if there's a lots of objects in my project. Is there solution?

you can do it with the MeasureIt addon: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/325668/how-to-measure-objects-in-blender-4-2/325675#325675
